# Error: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy

Tags: hadoop, compression, sqoop, snappy

I am importing data from RDBMS to hdfs using sqoop 1.4.6 using snappyCodec as compression and avro as file format. I have following components installed 
Hadoop 2.8.0 
Spark 2.1.0 
Hive 1.2.2 
Scala 2.11.8 
Cassandra 3.10 

When i try to import mysql table to hdfs using with following command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://******:****/retail_db --username **** --password **** --table order_items --compress --compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec --target-dir /user/test/order_items --as-avrodatafile
```

I'm getting following error:

```
Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
```

and it times out after trying to find this class. 
I tried solutions mentioned regarding this issue like mounting tmp and adding snappy jar file ( which is already present ) but none of them works. Anything I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying several solutions, i finally figured out the problem. Using --verbose flag with sqoop command showed that there were multiple snappy-xxx.jar files being imported from different components like

1. $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/
2. $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/
3. $SQOOP_HOME/lib/

    so there were 3 snappy jars being included.

**Solution:**
I made sure that only 1 file gets included in this case and error was resolved.